# Downloads Gallery plugin?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I am designing a blog for a software vendor.
They have a number of downloads available, both their own, and also from their clients.
Downloads are usually tools that can be bolted onto the main software products.

They want to have a slick interface to be able to search and download these items.

I am looking for Wordpress plugins that might fit the description?

What we are after, could be something like [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/gallery.html), or like [this](http://themehybrid.com/showcase/).

i.e. A thumbnail, name of tool, and maybe a user rating (not essential).  Hovering over the tool would provide more info.

Flexible on how it looks and feels, even something similar t[o Wordpress Plugins directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) might work.

Any clear plugin winners out there?

:EDIT:
Sounds like I should be looking at Custom Post Types.
From what I have read so far, looks good, but still looks like I will need to write a fair bit of code to get what I want.
- Would love to be proved wrong --> perhaps there is a custom post template for what I am after?
*(I will research further)*

Comment: Hello Simon,

Looking at that link it seems relatively easy what you want to do without the use of a plugin, use custom post types to list the downloads, jquery and php to list them as the example.  Manipulate the search to only search the download sections, all in all if your familiar with coding should take you around a day or two.

Comment: Im pretty new to jquery and php, but very willing to learn.  However, I am afraid I would need a more detailed answer around this to be able to mark it as resolved.  The answer also needs to be something that is easily managable in the long term - i.e. Others can add to the gallery without needing to dive into code.  (Thanks by the way)

Comment: Hello Simon i've added something below, but it is just the basics to get you started the hardest part is the jQuery i guess in this instance, if you are a novice at jQuery and PHP i would recommend that you commission this project to someone and get them to build this aspect of the website for you.

Answer (score 2):

to do something like this is relatively large as a project so I couldn't really post you the code to do what you exactly want, but you could commission this as a project for someone to help you with just that aspect of the project.

But here are the steps involved to do something like this:

## Step 1; Register custom post type

```
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'products',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'products' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'products' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 6,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
        'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','editor','custom-fields')
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'create_post_type');
```

Codex Link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

## Step 2; Display Custom Post type

the below code basically prints your custom post into a page, and has the html markup ready for styling and functioning for jQuery.

```
<ul> <!-- to hold the posts -->
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $post_per_page = 9; // -1 shows all posts & show 3 per line so 9 in total before showing the other pages
    $do_not_show_stickies = 1; // 0 to show stickies
    $args=array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    );
    $temp = $wp_query;  // assign orginal query to temp variable for later use
    $wp_query = null;
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( have_posts() ) : while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

    <?php $download_link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'download-link', $single = true); // custom field on post to allow entry of a http link for the download?>

    <li>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(200,300), array('title'  => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title)), ));?>
        <a href="#" class="trigger"><?php the_title();?></a>
    </li>

    <div class="tooltip">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(200,300), array('title'  => trim(strip_tags( $attachment->post_title)), ));?>
        <a href="<?php echo $download_link ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
        <?php the_content();?>
    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; $wp_query = $temp;  //reset back to original query ?>   
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
</ul>
```

To show the next and previous pages in a numbered format you can use a plugin such as WP-Pagination to get numbered pages like [1] [2] [3]

## Step 3; the jQuery

This is what would take the most time to implement but what you can do is look for a tooltip style plugin or write your own, but if you are writting one yourself all you have to do is is use the div in the above code  and add a .hide() to that;

then when the mouse hovers over a class="trigger" it will .show() that div, the div will hold the information for your mouse over for page sliding effects well that itself is a larger task.

But i hope the above helps you get started on your project.

Here are some jQuery Plugins that will help you along the way;

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/
http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Comment: Thanks Xavier. I will give it a shot and see how I go.  Will leave question open to see if anyone knows of a suitable plugin that could achieve this.  REmember, but requirements are not specific, just something similar.  Thanks again

Comment: How is it going Simon, have you managed to get something started yet ?  I was thinking about a jQuery tooltip plugin you can use if your still working on it can link it to you

Comment: Stil reading up on options, and some of the links you sent.  Would love to see this jQuery plugin.  Im happy to do some coding, but not from scratch - it will look amateur.

Comment: I've added a link to the tooltip plugin :)